# ACE_Mutex::acquire problem

Tags: c++

I have a mutex in my class with the following definition:

```
ACE_Mutex m_specsMutex;
```

When i use the acquire() method that takes no parameters everything works just fine. But when i use it with a time value (as follows) it just immediately returns with -1 value. I'm sure that this mutex hasn't been acquired anywhere else so it shouldn't return -1.

```
m_specsMutex.acquire(ACE_OS::gettimeofday() + ACE_Time_Value(30))
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is in errno after the failed called to acquire (is it ETIME or something else)?

Comment: @Samuel: Thanks for mentioning errno. errno is 40 and ACE_OS::strerror(errno) returns "Function not Implemented". What should i use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browing through the doxygen docs for ACE_Mutex, I don't understand how your code could possibly compile.  The time-out value (tv) is passed either by reference or a pointer so that acquire() can update the absolute time at which the mutex was acquired.  You cannot pass an expression.  Try it like this:

```
ACE_Time_Value time = ACE_OS::gettimeofday() + ACE_Time_Value(30);
m_specsMutex.acquire(&time);
```

Comment: I've already tried that but both ways compile and work just fine. I'm using VS2008 by the way.

Comment: Ditch the library.  CreateMutex, WaitForSingleObject, ReleaseMutex gets it done on Windows.

Comment: @nobugz, Thanks. It seems its the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on win32. I needed much time to find a solution and want to share it with you.

ACE_Mutex (=ACE_Thread_Mutex) is implemented using CRITICAL_SECTION for win32 environments. This is very fast but has no possibility to wait with a timeout.

Finally I used ACE_Process_Mutex instead of ACE_Mutex. This is implemented with a HANDLE -based mutex for win32 environments and can be used with timeout.

More information can be found here: http://flylib.com/books/en/3.19.1.83/1/#_/term_